# Queue multiple asyncAfter relative to eachother - Swift 3

Tags: ios, swift3

I'm trying to replay a series of points recorded from UITouch events to my draw handler.  I want each point to be draw 0.1 seconds after the last one.  Once I have the array of CGPoints I iterate through the array and queue a GDC dispatchAfter to call my draw method with the point.

```
override func replay(_ queue: DispatchQueue) {

    isReplaying = true

    for stroke in strokeHistory {

        var additionalTime = 0.0

        for curPoint in stroke.points {

            DispatchQueue.main.asyncAfter(deadline: DispatchTime.now() + additionalTime, execute: {
                [unowned self, s = stroke, lrp = stroke.lastReplayPoint] in
                s.lastReplayPoint = lrp
                switch curPoint.state {
                case .began:
                    self.strokeBegan(s, atPoint: curPoint)
                case .changed:
                    self.strokeMoved(s, toPoint: curPoint)
                case .ended:
                    self.strokeEnded(s, atPoint: curPoint)
                default :
                    NSLog("Point phase default.")
                }
            })

            additionalTime = additionalTime + 0.1
            stroke.lastReplayPoint = curPoint
        }
    }
}
```

The playback works but gradually slows down and draws large chunks of points at slower and slower intervals.  How can I queue these points up to be drawn with 0.1s inbetween them?

Answer (score 0):

There are a couple of possibilities:

1. If it's really slowing down, then it is likely that stroking the whole path each time. So, the latter strokes have more to draw and they take more time. Hence the slower rendering.

   You can solve this by periodically taking screen snapshots and then render the previous screen snapshot plus the new path. That way your paths are limited as to how long they are.
2. Also note that it might not be slowing down, but merely coalescing the timers together (which will happen if you have a bunch of `asyncAfter` calls in the future). When its coalescing, the overall speed should remain largely consistent, but it will coalesce them together, giving you more stuttering in your timers.

   You can fix this by using a repeating timer (which won't coalesce them together). Or if you create a one-shot timer, you can specify `DispatchSource.TimerFlag.strict` to opt out of coalescing.

---

But, even easier, you can avoid this problem entirely by using Core Animation to animate the stroking. It not only doesn't suffer this slower rendering of the latter points, but it's much easier and renders a smoother animation. For example, if you have a `path` specified for a `CAShapeLayer`:

```
let path: UIBezierPath = ...  // construct your path any way you want

let pathLayer = CAShapeLayer()
pathLayer.strokeColor = UIColor.blue.cgColor
pathLayer.fillColor = UIColor.clear.cgColor
pathLayer.lineWidth = 3
view.layer.addSublayer(pathLayer)
```

Then you can then animate the stroking of that path like so:

```
let stroke = CABasicAnimation(keyPath: "strokeEnd")
stroke.fromValue = 0.0
stroke.duration = 1.0              // change this as you see fit, perhaps saving the original time it took to capture the path and using that (or some fraction thereof) when animating the path
pathLayer.add(stroke, forKey: nil)
```

That yields, with a path with 7,200 points:

[image: programmatically created path animated]

Comment: I am not drawing the whole path or canvas each time, just the line segments to a buffer CGLayer and that minimum "dirty rect" into the view's draw() CGContext.  Some more info, the animation plays out as expected if I don't queue multiple dispatchAfters and instead do a recursive function taking the first point in the array, drawing it, removing it from the array, and repeating w/ delay inbetween until the array is empty.

Comment: @TylerWhite - Ok, if that's not it, then it's probably not really slowing down, but merely coalescing the timers (which happens if you schedule a bunch of separate timers in the future), yielding an animation that is roughly the same speed, but will appear to stutter more and more the further out you are. You can either opt out of coalescing (using `DispatchTimerSource` with `flags` of `DispatchSource.TimerFlag.strict`), or, much easier, just use a single repeating `Timer` or dispatch timer rather than a bunch of separate timers. That will prevent the coalescing.